# How to remove excess nail hole filler

Tags: wood

I recently had my windows and trim replaced and the contractor was very sloppy filling in the nail holes on the trim. There are big globs of whatever he use left on the wood any ideas on what I can use to safely remove the substance without damaging the wood?

Comment: Careful use of a single-edged razor blade should work.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the filler material used, but the most likely candidates would  be caulk or wood filler/putty.

**Caulk** remains somewhat flexible after drying. It will probably be white. You can trim it with a razor blade to remove the excess. Assuming the caulk is a paintable type, you can then apply primer and paint your trim to conceal the patch. If you need to apply more, simply smooth it with your finger or a putty knife while it's wet.

**Wood filler or putty** will dry hard. It will probably be some shade of brown. Most putties are designed to be sand-able, like real wood. Simply sand the patched area smooth with the surrounding wood, apply primer, and paint. Putty can come in a can or squeeze tube, and is usually applied with a putty knife (but a finger can work too).

If neither of these works for you, please post a picture so we can better identify the material.